# How to enable a jQuery Mobile button?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery 1.6, and jQuery Mobile Beta 1. I have a jQuery Mobile themed button which I initialize as disabled. During a certain event, I'd like to enable the button. The following code is what I'd expect to work:

```
$("#id").prop("disabled", false);
```

But it seems like this doesn't propagate up to the jQuery Mobile wrapping DOM elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution, per the jQuery Mobile docs page [Form Plugins Method](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/plugin-eventsmethods.html) is as follows:

```
$('#id').button('enable');
```