# check if jquery-mobile loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button

Is there anyway of detecting if the jquery-mobile/or any other library is loaded?

I know I could do a simple `$('#button').button('enable');` just as mentioned  here [How to enable a jQuery Mobile button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497131/how-to-enable-a-jquery-mobile-button) but for fun I just want to know if there is any way of detecting if a library is loaded, and then execute the code above

Comment: Is it not supposed to be enclosed inside the DOM Ready Handler `$(function() { $('#button').button('enable'); })`

Comment: @Sushanth-- I see... but still, want to know if there is a way of detecting if a library is loaded or not

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can check if one of the functions is there.

```
if ( $.mobile ) {
   //jq mobile loaded
} else {
  // not
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it with jQM:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    //apply overrides here
});
```

This is a moment when jQM starts to execute. It is executed only once.

You can read more about it here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

But in your case it is a bit different. You need to wait for DOM to be loaded to change something in page content, the best jQM practice for that case is a pagebeforeshow event :

```
$('#pageID').live('pagebeforeshow', function (event) {
    // Some code here
});
```

Comment: this does not answers the question